Truncation error bounds for a numerical solution of ODEs
We have the following ordinary differential equation
$$ y'(t) = f(t,y(t)), \: \text{for} \: t \in [t_{0}, t_{0} + T] $$
and the initial conditional $y(t_{0}) = \eta$ and $f(t,y(t))$ being Lipschitz in the second variable. Supposing that $h = T/N$ and $t_{n} = t_{0} + nh, 0 \leq n \leq N$, we will use the integration scheme
$$
y_{0}=\eta, \: x_{1}=y_{0} + hf(t_{0}, y_{0}), \: y_{2} = y_{0} + 2hf(t_{1}, x_{1}), \: y_{1} = y_{0}/4 + x_{1}/2 + y_{2}/4,
$$
and for the next steps
$$
y_{n+1} = y_{n-2} + \frac{9h}{4}f(t_{n}, y_{n}) + \frac{3h}{4}f(t_{n-2}, y_{n-2}). 
$$
I'm supposed to show the following bounds
$$ |y(t_{1}) - x_{1}| \leq \frac{M_{2}}{2}h^{2}, \:
|y(t_{2}) - y_{2}| \leq (\frac{M_{3}}{3} + LM_{2})h^{3}, \: 
|y(t_{1}) - y_{1}| \leq (\frac{M_{3}}{12} + \frac{LM_{2}}{4})h^{3}, $$
where $L$ is the Lipschitz constant and $M_{i}$ is the maximum of the $i$-th derivative of $y(t)$.
Now, the first one is pretty straightforward, using that $y(t_{1}) = y(t_{0}) + hy'(t_{0}) + \frac{h^{2}}{2} y''(\xi) $ and the assumptions we have. I am not too sure about the rest since I find myself with terms that I don't know to get rid off. Any tips?
Thank you in advance.

As you mentioned, the first is simple.
$y(t_1) = y(t_0) + h y'(t_0) + \frac{y''(\zeta)}{2}(h^2) = x_1 +  \frac{y''(\zeta)}{2}(h^2)$ by Taylor series of $y$.
For 2nd and 3rd, you need the Taylor series remainder form.
$$g(a + h) = g(a) + h g'(a) + \cdots + g^{(m)}(a)\frac{h^m}{m!} + \int_0^h g^{(m+1)}(a+s) \frac{(h - s)^m}{m!} ds $$
Then for your 2nd estimate:
$y(t_2) = y(t_0) + 2h y'(t_0) + 2h^2 y''(t_0) + \int_{0}^{2h} y'''(t_0 + s)\frac{(2h - s)^2}{2} ds $, and $$\begin{aligned}y_2 &= y_0 + 2h f(t_0 + h, y_0 + h f(t_0, y_0)) \\& = y_0 + 2h(f + h f_t + h f_y f + \int_0^{h} K''(s) (h - s) ds) \\& = y_0 + 2h f + 2 h^2 (f_t + f_y f) + 2h\int_0^{h} K''(s) (h - s) ds,\quad \text{use}\quad y'(t_0) = f,\quad y''(t_0) = f_t + f_y f\end{aligned}$$
Here we abuse the notations for $f, f_t, f_y$ a little to omit the default parameter $t_0, y_0$, and $K(s) = f(t_0 + s, y_0 + s f)$.
notice that $y''' = f_{tt} + 2f_{ty} f +  f_{yy} f^2 + f_{y}(f_{t} + f_y f)$, thus $K''(s) = y'''(t_0 + s) - f_y(t_0 + s, y_0 + s f) y''(t_0 + s)$. Then
$$\begin{aligned}y(t_2) - y_2 & = \int_0^h y'''(t_0 + s) \left(\frac{(2h-s)^2}{2} - 2h(h-s) \right) ds \\ &+ \int_h^{2h} y'''(t_0 + s)\frac{(2h-s)^2}{2} ds \\& + 2h \int_0^h f_y(t_0+s, y_0+ sf) y''(t_0+s) (h-s) ds \end{aligned} $$
The last term is bounded by $L M_2 h^3$. The 2nd term is bounded by $\frac{h^3}{6} M_3$. The first term is bounded by
$$M_3 \int_0^h \frac{s^2}{2} ds = \frac{h^3}{6}M_3$$
For the last one, simply use $$y(t_1) = y_0 + hy'(t_0) + \frac{y''(t_0)}{2}h^2 + \int_0^h y'''(t_0+s)\frac{(h-s)^2}{2} ds$$
and combine the previous derivation.
